# Grafana convert unix time to date in graphql query

Tags: graphql, grafana, unix-timestamp

Does anyone know how to convert unix time to date in graphql query?
I have something like this
[my panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TbL3.png)

I've got unix time in nanoseconds
Grafana version is 8.2.1

As I see it, I can't use math functions to divide by 1000 and get milliseconds so that I can then select the Date data type

Desired result is YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Thanks!

Comment: Grafana should recognize your timestamp right away. Try aliasing you filed as `time` (something like this `time: created_at`, as seen [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-aliases-graphql/))